# Implementing client-server, GUI StringBuilder issue

Tags: java, sockets, jakarta-ee, client-server, stringbuilder

Trying to make a client server program, specifically a hangman game.

I have 4 files: `KnockKnockServer`, `KnockKnockProtocol`,`Hangman` and `KnockKnockClient.`

`KnockKnockServer` runs, `KnockKnockClient` connects to it. `KnockKnockProtocol` handles the request from client. Client sends a request from user if `KnockKnockProtocol` recognize certain word or phrase it would provide an answer for the specific word. 
The Hangman file is a complete `Hangman` game(not client server) and I want to re-use some of it's methods like printing the Hangman dude. Taking that Hangman dude and display on the client side.

So I'm using string builder to be able to modify the string. But I got weird result. 
Should I use string builder or something else? 
What else do I need to fix so the client can receive the Hangman resources? 
Should I redesign this whole project?

Here is how the server prints out:

```
run:
  ____
  |  |
  |
  |
  |
  |
  |
  |
__|__

_ _ _ 
Wrong letters:   ____
  |  |
  |
  |
  |
  |
  |
  |
__|__

_ _ _ 
Wrong letters: 
s
a
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 minute 31 seconds)
```

Just weird that it prints out Hangman dude two times.

Here is what is displayed on the client side:

```
run:
Server: Connection Established.. Start hangman? (y/n)
y
Client: y
Server:   ____
a
Client: a
Server:   |  |
e
Client: e
Server:   |
i
Client: i
Server:   |
o
Client: o
Server:   |
s
Client: s
Server:   |
r
Client: r
Server:   |
r
Client: r
Server:   |
r
Client: r
Server: __|__
s
Client: s
Server: 
g
Client: g
Server: _ _ _ 
g
Client: g
Server: Wrong letters: 
h
Client: h
Server: You're supposed to say "Little Old Lady who?"! Try again. Knock! Knock!
BUILD STOPPED (total time: 1 minute 15 seconds)
```

The client to use string builder to rebuild string from server side draw a hangman. But it's not being drawn properly.

KnockKnockServer server side:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class KnockKnockServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.err.println("Usage: java EchoServer <port number>");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        //sets portNumber to argument run value
        int portNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        try ( 
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            PrintWriter out =
                new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        ) {

            String inputLine, outputLine;

            KnockKnockProtocol kkp = new KnockKnockProtocol();
            outputLine = kkp.processInput(null);
            out.println(outputLine);

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                outputLine = kkp.processInput(inputLine);
                out.println(outputLine);
                if (outputLine.equals("Bye."))
                    break;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception caught when trying to listen on port "
                + portNumber + " or listening for a connection");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

KnockKnockProtocol server side:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class KnockKnockProtocol {
    private static final int WAITING = 0;
    private static final int SENTKNOCKKNOCK = 1;
    private static final int SENTCLUE = 2;
    private static final int ANOTHER = 3;

    private static final int NUMJOKES = 5;

    private int state = WAITING;
    private int currentJoke = 1;

    private int counter = 0;

    private String[] clues = { "Turnip", "Little Old Lady", "Atch", "Who", "Who" };
    private String[] answers = { "Turnip the heat, it's cold in here!",
                                 "I didn't know you could yodel!",
                                 "Bless you!",
                                 "Is there an owl in here?",
                                 "Is there an echo in here?" };

    public String processInput(String theInput) {
            Hangman hman = new Hangman();
        String theOutput = null;

        if (state == WAITING) {
            theOutput = "Connection Established.. Start hangman? (y/n)";
            state = SENTKNOCKKNOCK;





        } else if (state == SENTKNOCKKNOCK) {
            //if (theInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Who's there?")) {
            if (theInput.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                //theOutput = clues[currentJoke];
                theOutput = hman.printCurrentState();
                System.out.println(theOutput);
                state = SENTCLUE;

            } else {
                theOutput = "You guessed a wrong word" + " failed attempts: " + counter++ +
                        " Try agian. Start hangman? (y/n)";
            }
        } else if (state == SENTCLUE) {
            if (theInput.equalsIgnoreCase(clues[currentJoke])) {
                theOutput = answers[currentJoke] + " Play again? (y/n)";
                state = ANOTHER;
            } else {
                theOutput = "You're supposed to say \"" + 
                clues[currentJoke] + 
                " who?\"" + 
                "! Try again. Knock! Knock!";
                state = SENTKNOCKKNOCK;
            }
        } else if (state == ANOTHER) {
            if (theInput.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                theOutput = "Guess a word";
                if (currentJoke == (NUMJOKES - 1))
                    currentJoke = 0;
                else
                    currentJoke++;
                state = SENTKNOCKKNOCK;
            } else {
                theOutput = "Bye.";
                state = WAITING;
            }
        }
        return theOutput;
    }
}
```

Hangman game server side:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Title:            Hangman
// Files:            Hangman.java
//////////////////////////// 80 columns wide //////////////////////////////////

import java.util.*;

/**
 * This program implements the word guessing game called Hangman.
 *
 * <p>Bugs: none known
 *
 * @author CS302, 2009,2012 modified by Jim Skrentny
 */
public class Hangman {

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // 1. CLASS VARIABLE
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private static String [] words =   //choose secret word from these
    {"geography", "cat", "yesterday", "java", "truck", "opportunity",
        "fish", "token", "transportation", "bottom", "apple", "cake",
        "remote", "pocket", "terminology", "arm", "cranberry", "tool",
        "caterpillar", "spoon", "watermelon", "laptop", "toe", "toad",
        "fundamental", "capitol", "garbage", "anticipate", "apple"};



    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // 2. INSTANCE VARIABLES
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private String secretWord;       // the chosen secret word
    private ArrayList<Character> correctLetters;   // correct guesses
    private ArrayList<Character> incorrectLetters; // incorrect guesses

    private Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in); // for user input



    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // 3. CONSTRUCTOR
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /**
     * Constructs a Hangman game.
     */
    public Hangman() {
        //REMOVE LINE BELOW WHEN DONE TESTING
        //this.secretWord = "miscellaneous";

        //Randomly choose a word from list of words
        //UNCOMMENT LINES BELOW TO PLAY WHEN DONE TESTING
        Random randIndex = new Random();
        int index = randIndex.nextInt(Hangman.words.length);
        this.secretWord = Hangman.words[index];

        this.correctLetters = new ArrayList<Character>();
        for (int i = 0; i < this.secretWord.length(); i++)
            this.correctLetters.add('_');
        this.incorrectLetters = new ArrayList<Character>();
    }



    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // 4. PUBLIC INSTANCE METHODS
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /**
     * playGame
     *
     * Play one game of Hangman until
     * the user wins (guesses all of the letters in the secret word)
     * or loses (guesses 7 incorrect letters):
     */
    public void playGame() {

        while (!gameOver()) {

            //Print the Hangman picture
            printHangman();

            //Print the correct guesses in the secret word
            for (int i = 0; i < this.correctLetters.size(); i++)
                System.out.print(this.correctLetters.get(i) + " ");

            //Print the incorrect letters that have been guessed
            System.out.print("\nWrong letters: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < this.incorrectLetters.size(); i++)
                System.out.print(this.incorrectLetters.get(i) + " ");

            //Prompt and read the next guess
            System.out.print("\nEnter a lower-case letter as your guess: ");
            String guess = stdin.nextLine();

            //Process the next guess
            handleGuess(guess.charAt(0));
        }

        System.out.println("The secret word was: " + secretWord);
        if (gameWon()) {
            System.out.println("Congratulations, you won!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry, you lost.");
            printHangman();
        }
    }

        /*
        -
        */
    public String printCurrentState() {
            //Print the Hangman picture
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(printHangman());

            //Print the correct guesses in the secret word
            for (int i = 0; i < this.correctLetters.size(); i++){
                            System.out.print(this.correctLetters.get(i) + " ");
                        sb.append(this.correctLetters.get(i) + " ");}


            //Print the incorrect letters that have been guessed
            System.out.print("\nWrong letters: ");
                        sb.append("\nWrong letters: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < this.incorrectLetters.size(); i++){
                System.out.print(this.incorrectLetters.get(i) + " ");
                        sb.append(this.incorrectLetters.get(i) + " ");}
            return sb.toString();
        }


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // 5. PRIVATE INSTANCE METHODS (HELPERS)
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /**
     * handleGuess
     *
     * If the guessed letter (parameter ch) is in the secret word
     * then add it to the array list of correct guesses and tell the user
     *      that the guess was correct;
     * otherwise, add the guessed letter to the array list of incorrect
     *      guesses and tell the user that the guess was wrong.
     *
     * @param ch the guessed letter
     */


    private void handleGuess(char ch) {
        boolean chInSecretWord = false;

        // go through the secret word character by character
        for (int i = 0; i < this.secretWord.length(); i++) {
            if (this.secretWord.charAt(i) == ch) { // if ch matches
                chInSecretWord = true;             // the guess was correct
                this.correctLetters.set(i, ch);    // update the user's guess
            }
        }



        if (chInSecretWord)
            System.out.println("The letter you guessed was correct!");

        else {  // the character was not in the secret word
            this.incorrectLetters.add(ch);
            System.out.println("Sorry, that letter is not in the secret word");
        }

        /////////////////////////
        // TODO FILL IN CODE HERE
        /////////////////////////
    }

    /**
     * gameWon
     *
     * Return true if the user has won the game;
     * otherwise, return false.
     *
     * @return true if the user has won, false otherwise
     */
    private boolean gameWon() {
        boolean won = true;  // initially assume the game has been won

            if (this.correctLetters.contains('_'))  // if there are any '_'
                won = false;               // the game has not been won

        return won;

        /////////////////////////
        // TODO FILL IN CODE HERE
        /////////////////////////

        // NOTE: THE LINE BELOW IS SO THE CODE WILL COMPILE
        // Replace it with appropriate code for your implementation
        //return false;
    }

    /**
     * gameLost
     *
     * Return true if the user has lost the game;
     * otherwise, return false.
     *
     * @return true if the user has lost, false otherwise
     */
    private boolean gameLost() {
        return this.incorrectLetters.size() >= 7;

        /////////////////////////
        // TODO FILL IN CODE HERE
        /////////////////////////

        // NOTE: THE LINE BELOW IS SO THE CODE WILL COMPILE
        // Replace it with appropriate code for your implementation
        //return false;
    }

    /**
     * gameOver
     *
     * Return true if the user has either won or lost the game;
     * otherwise, return false.
     *
     * @return true if the user has won or lost, false otherwise
     */
    private boolean gameOver() {
        return gameWon() || gameLost();
        /////////////////////////
        // TODO FILL IN CODE HERE
        /////////////////////////

        // NOTE: THE LINE BELOW IS SO THE CODE WILL COMPILE
        // Replace it with appropriate code for your implementation
        //return false;
    }

    /**
     * printHangman
     *
     * Print the Hangman that corresponds to the given number of
     * wrong guesses so far.
     *
     * @param numWrong number of wrong guesses so far
     */
    private String printHangman() {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        int poleLines = 6;   // number of lines for hanging pole
        System.out.println("  ____");
        System.out.println("  |  |");
                sb.append("  ____\n");
                sb.append("  |  |\n");

        int badGuesses = this.incorrectLetters.size();
        if (badGuesses == 7) {
            System.out.println("  |  |");
            System.out.println("  |  |");
                        sb.append("  |  |\n");
                        sb.append("  |  |\n");
        }

        if (badGuesses > 0) {              
            System.out.println("  |  O");
            poleLines = 5;
                        sb.append("  |  O\n");
        }
        if (badGuesses > 1) {
            poleLines = 4;
            if (badGuesses == 2) {
                System.out.println("  |  |");
                                sb.append("  |  |\n");
            } else if (badGuesses == 3) {
                System.out.println("  | \\|");
                                sb.append("  | \\|\n");
            } else if (badGuesses >= 4) {
                System.out.println("  | \\|/");
                                sb.append("  | \\|/\n");
            }
        }
        if (badGuesses > 4) {
            poleLines = 3;
            if (badGuesses == 5) {
                System.out.println("  | /");
                                sb.append("  | /\n");
            } else if (badGuesses >= 6) {
                System.out.println("  | / \\");
                                sb.append("  | / \\\n");
            }
        }
        if (badGuesses == 7) {
            poleLines = 1;
        }

        for (int k = 0; k < poleLines; k++) {
            System.out.println("  |");
                        sb.append("  |\n");
        }
        System.out.println("__|__");
        System.out.println();
                sb.append("__|__\n");
                sb.append("\n");
                return sb.toString();
    }



    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // 6. FOR TESTING PURPOSE ONLY
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /**
     * toString
     * 
     * Returns a string representation of the Hangman object.
     * Note that this method is for testing purposes only!
     * @return a string representation of the Hangman object
     */
    public String toString() {
        String s = "secret word: " + this.secretWord;

        s += "\ncorrect letters: ";
        for (int i = 0; i < this.correctLetters.size(); i++)
            s += this.correctLetters.get(i) + " ";

        s += "\nused letters: ";
        for (int i = 0; i < this.incorrectLetters.size(); i++)
            s += this.incorrectLetters.get(i) + " ";

        s += "\n# bad letters: " + this.incorrectLetters.size();

        return s;
    }

    private void setCurrentWord(String newWord) {
        this.secretWord = newWord;
    }

    private void setCorrectLetters(ArrayList<Character> newGuesses) {
        this.correctLetters = newGuesses;
    }

    private void setIncorrectLetters(ArrayList<Character> newUsedLetters) {
        this.incorrectLetters = newUsedLetters;
    }

    private void setBadGuesses(int newBadGuesses) {
        this.incorrectLetters.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < newBadGuesses; i++) {
            this.incorrectLetters.add('x');
        }
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // 7. PUBLIC CLASS METHOD - MAIN
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        /* Note initially the constructor sets the secret word to:
         * "miscellaneous".  Be sure to update the constructor when
         * you're ready to play the game.
         */

        Hangman game = new Hangman();

        /* 
         * A. Testing the constructor
         *
         * To test the constructor, we use the toString method
         * to see if the data members are as expected.
         */

        System.out.println("The CONSTRUCTED game is:\n" + game);
        System.out.println("\n======== END CONSTRUCTOR TEST  ========\n");
        // */

        /*
         * B. Testing gameWon
         */

        if (game.gameWon()) 
            System.out.println("Game should not be won at beginning");

        String str = "miscellaneous";
        game.setCurrentWord(str);
        ArrayList<Character> guesses = new ArrayList<Character>();

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
            guesses.add(str.charAt(i));
        game.setCorrectLetters(guesses);

        if (!game.gameWon()) {
            System.out.println(game);
            System.out.println("Game should be won");       
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i += 3) 
            guesses.set(i, '_');
        game.setCorrectLetters(guesses);

        if (game.gameWon()) {
            System.out.println(game);
            System.out.println("Game should NOT be won");
        }

        System.out.println("\n========   END gameWon TEST    ========\n");
       // */

        /*
         * C. Testing gameLost
         */

        game = new Hangman();  // start with a new game

        if (game.gameLost()) 
            System.out.println("Game should not be lost at beginning");

        game.setBadGuesses(3);
        if (game.gameLost()) {
            System.out.println(game);
            System.out.println("Game should not be lost");
        }

        game.setBadGuesses(7);
        if (!game.gameLost()) {
            System.out.println(game);
            System.out.println("Game should be lost");  
        }

        game.setBadGuesses(10);
        if (!game.gameLost()) {
            System.out.println(game);
            System.out.println("Game should be lost");
        }

        System.out.println("\n========   END gameLost TEST   ========\n");
        // */  

        /*
         * D. Testing gameOver
         *
         * Add your own similar tests as above.
         */ 


        System.out.println("\n========   END gameOver TEST   ========\n");
        // */  


        /*
         *  E. Testing handleGuess
         */

        game = new Hangman();  // start with a new game
        System.out.println(game);

        game.handleGuess('a');  // check a letter in the word
        System.out.println(game);

        game.handleGuess('q');  // check a letter not in the word
        System.out.println(game);

        game.handleGuess('m');  // check for first letter in word
        System.out.println(game);

        game.handleGuess('l');  // check a letter that appears more than once
        System.out.println(game);

        game.handleGuess('s');  // check last letter in word
        System.out.println(game);

        game.handleGuess('x');  // check another letter not in word
        System.out.println(game);
        System.out.println("\n======== END handleGuess TEST  ========\n");
        // */

        /* F. Test the playGame method
         * Do this after all the private methods have been tested.
         */

        game = new Hangman();  // start with a new game
        game.playGame();
        // */
    }

}
```

KnockKnockClient client side:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class KnockKnockClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        /*
        needs two arguments, host name and port number.
        */
        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.err.println(
                "Usage: java EchoClient <host name> <port number>");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        /*
        sets port number.
        */
        String hostName = args[0];
        int portNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

        /*
        try resource creates new Socket object with hostname and portnumber to connect to. 
        */
        try (
            Socket kkSocket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(kkSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(kkSocket.getInputStream()));
        ) {
            BufferedReader stdIn =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String fromServer;
            String fromUser;

            while ((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Server: " + fromServer);
                if (fromServer.equals("Bye."))
                    break;

                fromUser = stdIn.readLine();
                if (fromUser != null) {
                    System.out.println("Client: " + fromUser);
                    out.println(fromUser);
                }
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host " + hostName);
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to " +
                hostName);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OK. I'll play.. Who's there?

Comment: Passing the final result from the server is bad architecture. Pass the state data (v.g. "3 fails") and let the client represent that state as it suits better to its platform (maybe your ASCII art is too big for a cell phone).

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be in here:

```
while ((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Server: " + fromServer);
                if (fromServer.equals("Bye."))
                    break;

                fromUser = stdIn.readLine();
                if (fromUser != null) {
                    System.out.println("Client: " + fromUser);
                    out.println(fromUser);
                }
            }
```

**Short answer:**

The server writes multiple lines to display the hangman and **you are reading only one line** then you wait for the user to enter another character. You should read all the lines of the server input. To do this wrap your BufferedReader with a DataInputStream ( dis = new DataInputStream(in)) then use dis.readUTF() to get the whole server message.

**Long answer:**

The server sends you this string: `____\n  |  |\n  |\n  |\n  |\n.....` and you are only reading till the first `\n`. Read the whole message (untill in.readLine() is null or use DataInputStream as I said above) then ask the client for a new guess.

Answer (score 0):

Since your clients share the server console for output you should synchronize the output for each client

```
synchronized (this){
  theOutput = hman.printCurrentState();
}
```

`StringBuilder` is ok because a new instance of `hman` is created. It doesn't share the buffer.